# Inserting M2M Relation into Table

Tags: django, orm

I'm trying to insert a relationship into a many to many table defined in my `Task` model.  When I try to `add()` the relationship I get an error that the `Queryset has no attribute user_task`.  What do I need to do to insert this relationship?

`models.py`

```
class Task(models.Model):
    user_task = models.ManyToManyField(AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

`views.py`

```
def create_usertask(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        task = Task.objects.filter(id=request.POST['id'])
        task.user_task.add(request.user.id)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/tasks/%s' % request.POST['id'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
task = Task.objects.filter(id=request.POST['id'])
```

this is a queryset. Whereas, you can reference the foreignkey/m2m field only on objects, (and not querysets)

You can do something like this:

```
for t in task:
    t.user_task.add(request.user)
```

Also, I would check if `request.user.is_authenticated()` or add a decorator `@login_required` to make sure it works as intended.

Comment: Thank you, I'll do that.